# repalce content using string_replace

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

i have repalce a string `color:#000000` with `color:#ffffff`.

The content in datasase with fieldname data is

```
style="width:720px; height:700px;font-size:13px;color:#000000"
```

The retrived values from the database is in

```
$res = $row->data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try php replace function [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

eg:

str_replace ("#000000", "#ffffff", $string_var);

Answer (score 0):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo str_replace("000000","ffffff",$res);
```